# How to check in batch file if some folder which contains specified string in name exists

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to check in batch file for existance of folder. But I don't want to check for full know name but for some "pattern".

For example:
Standard way

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0" (
do something
)
```

But I would like to achieve something like that:
if exist PATH WITH FOLDER NAME WHICH CONTAINS string "Reader" THEN
(
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular wildcard syntax for the *final* path component;

```
C:\>if exist "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader *" echo 1
1
```

Comment: In Windows a path name may contain _several_ * wildcards. For example, to check for a folder that contain "Reader" in _any_ place: `if exist "c:\Program Files\Adobe\*Reader*" echo 1`